# How to get chmod (octal) permissions of the folder in the terminal?

Tags: directory, chmod

I can look in properties of this folder but I want to get properties fast and in digits (octal, e.g. `755`, etc.)

What am I to type in terminal to know the chmod of the file or folder I want?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> What am i to type in terminal to know the chmod of the folder i want?

`stat -c %a FILE_OR_FOLDER_PATH`

e.g. `stat -c %a /etc` shows `755`

Comment: I'm getting `stat: illegal option -- c`, 
`usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]`.

Comment: For MacOS users use `stat -f %A FILE_OR_FOLDER_PATH` - [source](https://osxdaily.com/2018/09/06/get-file-permissions-octal-number-mac-command-line/)

Answer (score 6):

```
stat FILE_OR_FOLDER_PATH
```

this is quicker but displays the whole lot

Answer (score 5):

#### GNU find

Makes use of `%m` format for `-printf` flag.

```
$ find /etc/ -maxdepth 0 -printf "%m\n"                                                                                                                                                 
755
```

or

```
$ find /etc/ -prune -printf "%m\n"                                                                                                                                                      
755
```

#### Python

```
$ python -c 'import os,sys;print(oct(os.stat(sys.argv[1]).st_mode))' /etc                                                                                                               
040755
```

Or if we want to only get the owner-group-other permission bits only:

```
$ python -c 'import os,sys;print(oct(os.stat(sys.argv[1]).st_mode)[-3:])' /etc                                                                                                          
755
```

#### Perl

Via `File::stat`, pretty much same as in the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html):

```
$ perl -le 'use File::stat; $fs=stat($ARGV[0]);printf "%o\t%s\n",$fs->mode & 07777,$ARGV[0]' /etc                                                                                       
755 /etc
```